# Access SMB share through docker image or through docker host's connection to SMB share?

Tags: docker, security, smb

I have a service or three that needs access to the same SMB share. The service(s) is running inside a Docker container. I think my choices are:

1. Have the Docker container(s) where the service(s) is running mount the SMB share itself
2. Have the host of the Docker container(s) mount the SMB share and then share it with the Docker container(s) where the service(s) is running

Which is better from a best practices perspective (which should probably include security as a dimension)?

Am I missing an option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In standard Docker, you should almost always mount the filesystem on the host and then use a bind mount to attach the mounted filesystem to a container.

Containers can't usually call **mount**(2), a typical image won't contain **smbclient**(1) or **mount.cifs**(8), and safely passing credentials into a container is tricky.  It will be much easier to do the mount on the host, and you can use standard images against the mounted filesystem without having to customize them to add site-specific tools.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to mount the SMB shares on the host system as normal, for example if you are on Linux using `mount` and `fstab`. Afterwards you can use docker volumes to add the SMB shares, on your host system to your containers as volumes.

Advantages of using docker volumes are explained in the docker documentation.

More information about docker volumes in the docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/